# How to access the result_array() while loop variable outside while in codeigniter model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not able to access the while loop variable outside of the loop in CodeIgniter model

my model

```
$result=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product_categories where type='product'");
$result1 = $result->num_rows();
if($result1>0)
{
$outputfinal['value']='true';
$output[]='';
while ($e=$result->result_array()){

$output[]=$e;

}
}
print_r($output);
die();
```

if I tried to print. I am getting following error please help.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in
```

Comment: It seems to be a memory problem, so I guess you'll have to edit your `php.ini` file to allow more than 128M (134,217,728 bytes).

Comment: if you change php.ini it will colapse your browser with so much info, try to print part of data like `print_r($output[5]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result->result_array()` already returns an **array** with all records from a query, there's no need to use `while`:

```
$result=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product_categories where type='product'");
$result1 = $result->num_rows();
if($result1>0) {
    $outputfinal['value'] = 'true';
    $output = $result->result_array();
}
print_r($output);
die();
```

`while ($e=$result->result_array())` **always** returns `truthy` value and your loop runs **endlessly**, causing above-mentioned memory error.